# How to use Panel as Button Menu in Sencha Architect?

Tags: button, extjs, menu, panel, sencha-architect

**PROGRAMS USED:** Sencha Architect with ExtJS 4.2.

**CURRENT SITUATION:** My Button use a Start Menu style. The Start Menu is Panel type. I put both the Button and the Start Menu Panel in a Taskbar. Since I can't point the Button to use the Panel as a Menu in Architect (it automatically creates a Menu type when I click create Menu), so I use this code in the Taskbar afterLayout event:

```
container.getComponent('StartButton').menu = container.getComponent('StartMenuView');
```

**PROBLEMS:** The StartMenu displayed correctly when I click the Button, but I can't close it no matter where I click. What did I miss? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to switch to another much simpler approach that I've just figured: Use my "StartMenu" Panel as a Menu Item in my "Start" Button.